# Handling concurrent transactions with the sqlite mutexes?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, sqlite, transactions

I'm writing a server for a collaborative todo list. My server has to answer multiple clients through a publish/subscribe service.

For example, here is the code that updates the text of a todo entry :

```
db.run("BEGIN;");
var version = undefined;
try
{
    db.get("SELECT version FROM todos WHERE id = ?", [msg.id], function (err, row)
    {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("version : " + row.version);
        version = row.version + 1;

        db.run("UPDATE todos SET title = ?, version = ? WHERE id = ?", [msg.title, version, msg.id], function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            db.run("COMMIT;");
            publish("broadcast", {cmd: "edit", todo: {id: msg.id, title: msg.title, version: version}});
        });
    });   
}
catch (err)
{
    db.run("ROLLBACK;");
    console.log(err);
    publish(msg.sender, {err: err, request: msg});
}
```

The issue is this :
whenever a thread is updating a todo, a second update request can arrive and trigger the start of a new transaction, which results in an error : "cannot start a transaction from within a transaction".

It seems the easiest way to solve this would be to acquire a mutex before starting a transaction.
I didn't find a simple, convincing, way of using mutexes with node, and I'm wondering whether the best solution would be to extend the node sqlite API to wrap the sqlite3_mutex_enter() and related functions.

Comment: If node.js does not have built-in mutexes, why are you using it?

Comment: That's actually a good point. I'm writing an example for a publish/subscribe service, and I wanted it to be as easy as possible to test on one's computer. I want my code to require as little configuration as possible to run. The client-side app is made with javascript and vue.js. SQLite requires no configuration, and is installed with only one npm command. I'm actually using node for the first time, and those choices made sense with the knowledge I had at the time. Maybe should I switch to Python...